# Specifying conditions on eager loaded associations returns ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The problem is that when a `Restaurant` does not have any `MenuItems` that match the condition, ActiveRecord says it can't find the `Restaurant`. Here's the relevant code:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :meals, through: :menu_items

  def self.with_meals_of_the_week
    includes({menu_items: :meal}).where(:'menu_items.date' => Time.now.beginning_of_week..Time.now.end_of_week)
  end
end
```

And the sql code generated:

```
Restaurant Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT DISTINCT "restaurants".id FROM "restaurants"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "menu_items" ON "menu_items"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "meals" ON "meals"."id" = "menu_items"."meal_id" WHERE
"restaurants"."id" = ? AND ("menu_items"."date" BETWEEN '2012-10-14 23:00:00.000000'
AND '2012-10-21 22:59:59.999999') LIMIT 1←[0m  [["id", "1"]]
```

However, according to this part of the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations), this shouldn't be happening:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.visible", true)
```

If, in the case of this includes query, there were no comments for any posts, all the posts would still be loaded.

Comment: Does this work? includes(:menu_items).where('menu_items.date' => Time.now.beginning_of_week..Time.now.end_of_week)

Comment: No, exactly the same problem. And that way I'd still need to somehow include the `meal` for each `menu_item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL generated is a correct translation of your query. But look at it,
just at the SQL level (i shortened it a bit):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  "restaurants"
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  "menu_items" ON "menu_items"."restaurant_id" = "restaurants"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  "meals" ON "meals"."id" = "menu_items"."meal_id" 
WHERE 
  "restaurants"."id" = ? 
AND 
  ("menu_items"."date" BETWEEN '2012-10-14' AND '2012-10-21')
```

the left outer joins do the work you expect them to do: restaurants
are combined with menu_items and meals; if there is no menu_item to
go with a restaurant, the restaurant is still kept in the result, with
all the missing pieces (menu_items.id, menu_items.date, ...) filled in with NULL

now look aht the  second part of the where: the BETWEEN operator demands,
that menu_items.date is not null!  and this
is where you filter out all the restaurants without meals.

so we need to change the query in a way that makes having null-dates ok.

going back to ruby, you can write:

```
  def self.with_meals_of_the_week
    includes({menu_items: :meal})
       .where('menu_items.date is NULL or menu_items.date between ? and ?', 
            Time.now.beginning_of_week, 
            Time.now.end_of_week
        )
  end
```

The resulting SQL is now

```
.... WHERE (menu_items.date is NULL or menu_items.date between '2012-10-21' and '2012-10-28')
```

and the restaurants without meals stay in.

Comment: You know, this whole thing was an opportunity to learn more about Rails. My initial problem involved doing `Restaurant.with_meals_of_the_week.find(params[:id])` in my Restaurant show action but I eventually found out that doing this `@restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:id])` and then `@menu_items = @restaurant.menu_items.of_the_week` was as efficient as it could possibly be. However, in an index action, the type of query you provided will be really useful. And you've made me realise that I should pay more attention to the generated SQL. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in Rails Guide, all Posts in your query will be returned only if you will not use "where" clause with "includes", cause using "where" clause generates OUTER JOIN request to DB with WHERE by right outer table so DB will return nothing.

Such implementation is very helpful when you need some objects (all, or some of them - using where by base model) and if there are related models just get all of them, but if not - ok just get list of base models.

On other hand if you trying to use conditions on including tables then in most cases you want to select objects only with this conditions it means you want to select Restaurants only which has meals_items.

So in your case, if you still want to use only 2 queries (and not N+1) I would probably do something like this:

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :meals, through: :menu_items

  cattr_accessor :meals_of_the_week

  def self.with_meals_of_the_week
    restaurants = Restaurant.all
    meals_of_the_week = {}
    MenuItems.includes(:meal).where(date: Time.now.beginning_of_week..Time.now.end_of_week, restaurant_id => restaurants).each do |menu_item|
      meals_of_the_week[menu_item.restaurant_id] = menu_item  
    end
    restaurants.each { |r| r.meals_of_the_week = meals_of_the_week[r.id] }

    restaurants
  end
end
```

Update: Rails 4 will raise Deprecation warning when you simply try to do  conditions on  models

Sorry for possible typo.

Comment: No, that's not it. I'm using this method like this: `Restaurant.with_meals_of_the_week.find(params[:id])` so I'm looking for a single restaurant that I know that exists, including the meals that match that condition. The problem is, when there are no meals that match it, then the record is not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some misunderstanding of this

> If there was no where condition, this would generate the normal set of two queries.
>
> If, in the case of this includes query, there were no comments for any
>   posts, all the posts would still be loaded. By using joins (an INNER
>   JOIN), the join conditions must match, otherwise no records will be
>   returned.
>   [[from guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations)]

I think this statements doesn't refer to the example `Post.includes(:comments).where("comments.visible", true)`
but refer to one without `where` statement `Post.includes(:comments)`

So all work right! This is the way LEFT OUTER JOIN work.

---

So... you wrote: "If, in the case of this includes query, there were no comments for any posts, all the posts would still be loaded." Ok! But this is true ONLY when there is NO `where` clause! You missed the context of the phrase.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but that's not what it seems to imply. You'll notice that in the last 2 sentences you quoted, `includes` and `joins` have a console font so it means it they are referencing 2 methods/functions. And, in my opinion, those sentences imply that if you use `includes` the parent model will still be loaded regardless of the conditions but if you use `joins` then the conditions must match.

Comment: No, its not true. Sentences imply that 'If there was no where condition' and 'there were no comments for any posts' so `Post.includes(:comments)` will generate `LEFT JOIN` and return all posts, but `Posts.joins(:comments)` will generate `INNER JOIN` and return empty set.